# Disable Spring scheduling when running on jboss

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, jboss, scheduled-tasks

We have a Spring 4 webapplication which use `@EnableScheduling` and `@Scheduled`.

On some of our testservers we don't want scheduling to be active. We have solved this by adding a profile to the configuration that have the `@EnableScheduling` annotation.

When running on jetty on my mac that works fine. When running on jboss (EAP 6.3) scheduling is enabled even if I delete the `@EnableScheduling` annotation.

Can it be something on the jboss server that turns on Spring scheduling? Any other ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will suggest you to control your scheduler job via property:

```
@Value(..)
private boolean enabled;

@Scheduled
public void myJob() {
  if (enabled) {
    // do things
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for answering! This is one possible solution, but what I would like to know is why scheduling is enabled when running on jboss (EAP 6.3) even when we don't have a `@EnableScheduling` in our webapplication.