# Disable Spring Scheduler

Tags: spring, scheduler, spring-scheduled

I have a common maven project, where 4 different application projects (App01, App02, App03 and App04) extend from it. This common project has a Spring Scheduler job (JobA), where the cron expression (6 fields) is at application.properties file. I would like to only enable JobA at App01, App03, App04 but not App02. All applications have other jobs to run. How do I achieve this?

This [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37113557/418439) can't fit me as I do not have permission to edit the code. It is not using Quartz which has 7th field (year) that I can set to year in pass. I can't set it to invalid date (e.g. 31 Feb) as Spring will throw below exception during startup.

```
Invalid cron expression <xxx> led to runaway search for next trigger
```

Comment: Since you have different schedulers in app1 and app2 you should not put the scheduler in common project. Instead you can keep some abstract classes in common project and its implementation should belongs to the child projects.

Comment: Agreed with @vipincp, as you would get chance to override the scheduler behavior